# Asp.NET MVC: how to inject ViewBag/ViewMode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model

I have ModelFactoryService, which is responsible for creating ViewModels. It create ViewModel itself and add all necessary data(for listboxes etc.) to ViewBag for later use by View.

Here is IModelFactoryService interface:

```
public interface IModelFactoryService
{
    TranslationViewModel CreateTranslationViewModel(dynamic viewBag, TranslationViewModel.TranslationFormModel translationFormModel = null);
    TranslationViewModel.TranslationFormModel CreateTranslationFormModel();

    InterpretationViewModel CreateInterpretationViewModel(dynamic viewBag, InterpretationViewModel.InterpretationFormModel interpretationFormModel = null);
    InterpretationViewModel.InterpretationFormModel CreateInterpretationFormModel();
}
```

I would rather pass ViewBag(from current Controller) through constructor, like this:

```
public class ModelFactoryService : IModelFactoryService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly ICacheService _cacheService;
    private readonly dynamic _viewBag;

    #region ctor

    public ModelFactoryService(IRepository repository, ICacheService cacheService, dynamic viewBag)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _cacheService = cacheService;
        _viewBag = viewBag;
    }

    #endregion
    ...
```

I use StructureMap as IoC/DI container, but i dont know how to configure it. Any advice?

PS: I did not found better way how to pass additional data(for ListBoxes etc.) to Views. I dont want my Views to access DB(that's bad thing) and if i pass data as model's properties than they are accessible only by that model not by any partial or master page like they are in Viewbag..

Comment: You might want to have a look at "Ninject" to do the setup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031678/getting-started-with-ninject-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Ok, the problem is, i dont know how to configure StructureMap(or even any IoC/DI container) to inject ViewBag dependency. May be it is not possible, becouse at the time of container configuration(Application_Start), there is no reference to ViewBag controller property.