# How to get instance from Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

Below is NinjectHttpApplication configuration..

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
        public MvcApplication()
        {
            Error += NinjectWebsiteApplication_Error;
        }
}    

protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load<ApplicationConfig>();
        return kernel;
}

void NinjectWebsiteApplication_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        ILogger _iLogger = **//How to get instance of Applogger here from Ninject kernel..**
}
```

Below is the ApplicationConfig class...

```
public class ApplicationConfig : NHibernateNinjectModule
{

    public ApplicationConfig()
    {
     //other settings such as ddl script generation is present here
    }
    public override void Load()
    {                
        base.Load();
        Bind<ILogger>().To<AppLogger>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void NinjectWebsiteApplication_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     var kernel = CreateKernel();
     ILogger _iLogger = kernel.Get<ILogger>();
}
```

Ok, as it seems `NinjectHttpApplication` stores generated kernel object in

```
public IKernel Kernel
{
    get { return _kernel; }
}
```

So you could rewrite above as

```
void NinjectWebsiteApplication_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     ILogger _iLogger = Kernel.Get<ILogger>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do we need to create the kernel again to access the instance. Because in ApplicationConfig(), we have many other things going on such as creating ddl scripts for the application. So, when error event is raised, CreateKernel() gets called and scripts get generated again. I realized I need this instance in action filter too and tried with "inject" attribute on the property, but its giving object reference error. Does inject attribute or readonly property of the interface work in this case..

Comment: How do we access _kernel variable. Do I require something like this?... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031678/getting-started-with-ninject-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Nono, Kernel variable is public, so you just access it. Note, variable you need to access is Kernel, not private _kernel

Comment: It says .. [Deprecated] IKernel NinjectHttpApplication.Kernel
Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication.Kernel is obsolete: "Do not use Ninject as Service Locator"

Comment: I think static variable for kernel works fine. I also tried with (ILogger)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ILogger)), and it works. But I choose to use static variable than dependencyresolver. Thanks for your insight Archil :-)